# File not cacheing on AWS Elastic Map Reduce

Tags: python, hadoop, amazon-web-services, elastic-map-reduce

I'm running the following MapReduce on AWS Elastic MapReduce:

> ./elastic-mapreduce --create --stream --name CLI_FLOW_LARGE --mapper
>   s3://classify.mysite.com/mapper.py --reducer
>   s3://classify.mysite.com/reducer.py --input
>   s3n://classify.mysite.com/s3_list.txt --output
>   s3://classify.mysite.com/dat_output4/ --cache
>   s3n://classify.mysite.com/classifier.py#classifier.py --cache-archive 
>   s3n://classify.mysite.com/policies.tar.gz#policies --bootstrap-action
>   s3://classify.mysite.com/bootstrap.sh --enable-debugging
>   --master-instance-type m1.large --slave-instance-type m1.large --instance-type m1.large

For some reason the cacheFile `classifier.py` is not being cached, it would seem.  I get this error when the `reducer.py` tries to import it:

```
  File "/mnt/var/lib/hadoop/mapred/taskTracker/hadoop/jobcache/job_201204290242_0001/attempt_201204290242_0001_r_000000_0/work/./reducer.py", line 12, in <module>
    from classifier import text_from_html, train_classifiers
ImportError: No module named classifier
```

`classifier.py` is most definitely present at `s3n://classify.mysite.com/classifier.py`.  For what it's worth, the policies archive seems to load in just fine.

Comment: I think it's probably getting cached, but there is something wrong with your python path. Are reducer.py and classifier.py getting cached into the same directory? If not, you'll have to fiddle with `sys.path`

Comment: I thought that cached stuff was in the working directory?

Comment: Actually, you're right!  Posting the solution I found now..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know how to fix this problem in EC2, but I've seen it before with Python in traditional Hadoop deployments. Hopefully the lesson translates over.

What we need to do is add the directory `reduce.py` is in to the python path, because presumably `classifier.py` is in there too. For whatever reason, this place is not in the python path, so it is failing to find `classifier`.

```
import sys
import os.path

# add the directory where reducer.py is to the python path
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(__file__))
# __file__ is the location of reduce.py, along with "reduce.py"
# dirname strips the file name and only gives the directory
# sys.path is the python path where it looks for modules

from classifier import text_from_html, train_classifiers
```

The reason why your code might work locally is because of the current working directory in which you are running it from. Hadoop might not be running it from the same place you are in terms of the current working directory.

Answer (score 1):

orangeoctopus deserves credit for this from his comment.  Had to append the working directory system path:

`sys.path.append('./')`

Also, I recommend anyone who has similar issues to me to read this great article on using Distributed Cache on AWS:
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=152538

Comment: this is weird. I think python already has `.` in the path. I actually had an answer suggesting this but verified that `.` is in the path.... so I switched it to a comment :).

Comment: I undeleted it in case you want to see the details.